# How to write a dictionary into a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

```
node_dict = {}
node_dict['brand'] = ['tacobell']
node_dict['category'] = ['food', 'fastfood']
node_dict['product'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to write it to CSV file like:

```
brand        category     product

tacobell     food         a      
             fastfood     b
                          c
                          d
```

In each column, brand, category, product, the number of rows may be different. For example, under 'brand', there is only one row, the 2nd and 3d will be empty.

How to write them to a CSV file? I thought I should write column by column.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: No. no pandas, but I can if it is the way to go.

Comment: @ling That output isn’t CSV at all, please clarify things. Can you share some more context for this? That will help determine whether or not using Pandas is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k) for k,v in node_dict.items()], 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      brand  category product
0  tacobell      food       a
1       NaN  fastfood       b
2       NaN       NaN       c
3       NaN       NaN       d
```

You can then use `df.to_csv` to make it as a csv file:

```
print(df.to_csv('/path/you/want.csv', sep='\t', index=False))
```

Output:

```
brand   category    product
tacobell    food    a
    fastfood    b
        c
        d
```

Comment: How to make the csv delimiter = '\t'?

Comment: @ling I've edited my answer

Comment: That's good. I think I need excel sheet to make it easy reading. The csv is hard to read due to different length of columns.

Comment: @ling You can try using [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to begin with.

Comment: How to control the order of the columns I want to specify?

Answer (score 1):

Or use the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(node_dict, map(pd.Series, node_dict.values()))))
df.to_excel('/path/to/file.xlsx', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want solution without `pandas`:

```
node_dict = {}
node_dict['brand'] = ['tacobell']
node_dict['category'] = ['food', 'fastfood']
node_dict['product'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(node_dict)
    for v in zip_longest(*node_dict.values(), fillvalue=''):
        writer.writerow(v)
```

Creates this csv:

[image]